# installing manual gradle in android studio because stick sync gradle

Tags: gradle, synchronization

i have Linux mint and i want create first project by android studio but when i run android studio and synced "gradle" ,stick sync gradle on "app_debug Compile". please help me that how installing manual ' gradle '  .
tip:i do not have wrapper folder in the '.gradle' folder for install manual.
in the ". gradle" folder is 3 folder Whose name is "caches" "daemon" and "native". I don't know where to cope and paste 'gradle 2.8-all.zip' file.
please help me